# How to run script on Linux without password?

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint

I created a script that runs when I press a combination of keys, it means that I call my "script.py" from my "keyboard customize shortcuts".

It does not work properly because when I run my script from the terminal, I have to type my sudo password.

Just to be more clear, if I run my script without sudo, it shows this: **ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.**

So, it must be like this `sudo python3 script.py`, then it ask for my password (which I rather to not).

Comment: That's actually a good question and IMO should not be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

I created a file inside "`/etc/sudoers.d`" named "script" without extension.

Inside the script file I put "`myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user/Documents/Scripts/script.py`".

Then I gave the right permissions with `"chmod +x /home/user/Documents/Scripts/script.py`"

Finally I put "`sudo /home/user/Documents/Scripts/script.py`" on my custom shortcut.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things to blame for this:

1. You are logged in as root by default (not recommended) and so when you installed the library with `pip3 install theLibrary`, you installed it on the sudo account. Trying running `sudo pip3 install theLibrary`, or just create a new user account.
2. You are running this in IDLE, and you did not provide it with root privileges. You could fix this by running `sudo idle` first.
3. The quick fix: You could log in as `sudo` before running anything and stay as sudo for the duration of your session (so you wouldn't have to type your password every time) by running `sudo -i` and then typing your password once when prompted.

Comment: Hello there Victor,

When I tried to install with "pip3 install keyboard", it said that I have to do it with root.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied.

About IDLE, am not using it, just a simple ".py" file executable.

With "sudo -i" you are right, I type my password once and I run the script without typing it again but I have to do it manually, so ... I does not solve the issue.

Comment: I created a ".sh" file to execute my script.py ... if I double click it, works fine ... when I use my shortcut key combinations it doesn't.  Any suggestion?